# How to send ctrl + u + enter and ctrl + v + enter using expect4j java library?

Tags: java, expect, jsch

Basically I would like to know how to send three key combinations while using expect4j java library.
Enter key can be sent as send("\r"). Similarly how to do for three key combinations. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, try `send("\x15")`
For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, try `send("\x16")`

I'm not sure about expect4j, but that's what you'd send with Tcl expect.

Comment: Thanks glenn.. The ascii codes are correct but it doesn't work in expect4j java code..